# ¿Como mostrar datos separados por coma?

Tags: mysql

> Tengo esta tabla llamada tipo_enfermedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tengo esta otra llamada sintomas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Y hago esta consulta usando LEFT JOIN, me  muestra esto, lo que no logro hacer es que me muestre los datos de descripcion_sintoma separados por coma, es decir si en cod_sintoma tengo [1,4] en descripcion_sintoma me muestre [dolor, aturdimiento]

```
Select te.cod_tipo_enfermedades AS codigo, te.descripcion_tipo_enfermedades AS enfermedad, te.cod_sintomas,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.descripcion_sintoma SEPARATOR ',') FROM tipo_enfermedades te LEFT JOIN sintomas s ON s.cod_sintomas =
te.cod_sintomas GROUP by te.cod_tipo_enfermedades
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que agregar `s.descripcion_sintoma` al grupo, mediante: `GROUP BY te.cod_tipo_enfermedades, enfermedad, s.descripcion_sintoma`. Y cuando postees preguntas aquí pon el texto de la consulta en vez de imágenes. Así se puede eventualmente copiar el texto para hacer pruebas, mientras que las imágenes en este caso no sirven de nada.

Comment: Por favor, añáde siempre la descripción de tablas y tus consultas como texto. Replicar tus problemas usando imágenes es muchísimo más dispendioso.

Comment: En lugar de eso, deberías normalizar la estructura de tus tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos te pondré el siguiente ejemplo:

**Tabla1:**

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ id       ║  departamentos    ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ 1,2,4             ║
║ 2        ║ 4,5               ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

**Tabla 2(departamentos):**

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id       ║    nombre       ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Departamento 1  ║
║ 2        ║ Corp Admin      ║
║ 3        ║ Ventas          ║
║ 4        ║ Arte            ║
║ 5        ║ Marketing       ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

**el Query seria:**

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 as t1 LEFT JOIN tabla2 as t2 ON find_in_set(t2.id, 
t1.departamentos)
```

Resultado:

```
 ╠══════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
 ║ 1        ║ Departamento 1, Corp Admin, Arte ║
 ║ 2        ║ Arte, Marketing                  ║
 ╚══════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación: [find_in_set](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo!!